# OS X kernel lock virtual address space into physical memory

Tags: c, macos, kernel, mach

To allocate memory I do like that:

```
uint64_t _addr = 0x00;

kern_return_t err = mach_vm_allocate(mach_task_self(), &_addr, size, VM_FLAGS_ANYWHERE);
    if (err != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        printf("failed to allocate %s\n", mach_error_string(err));

    }
```

But can someone please show me how to prevent that memory from being paged to the swap area? In Windows there is VirtualLock.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to make sure a process never page faults when accessing the memory? Or are you attempting to secure the data by preventing it from being written to disk? If the latter, then wiring it may not be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work to use [`mach_vm_wire()`](https://yoursubtitle.blogspot.com/2009/11/section-86-mach-vm-user-space-interface.html#title-IDARN4YG) for this. It's not clear if you were asking about doing this from kernel code (e.g. a kext) or from user code. If from user space, you may need root privileges to do this.